# How to click click on either of two images to remove them both?

Tags: javascript

When you click the play button or the image, I want both images to go away.

I've targeted both of the elements in the nodelist, but when I click, only one of them goes away. The second one goes away only if I make a second click. I need them both to go away at the same time.

**How do I click on either of two images to make them both go away?**

```js
const clickToPlay = document.querySelectorAll('.one, .two');
console.log("I see both objects: " + Array.prototype.slice.call(clickToPlay));

clickToPlay.forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.play {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b" class="one" alt="">
 <div class="play two" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply listen to the `click` on the `container` then remove the images:

```js
const container = document.querySelectorAll(".container")[0];

container.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
  Array.from(imgs).forEach((img) => img.remove());
});
```

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-morning-jnx3k

Comment: I updated my original post. I made a mistake when I originally submitted it. The play button isn't supposed to be an image... it's a pure css element. Any ideas on this with the change?

Comment: This is what I ended up going with: [https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-brook-0sr30?file=/src/styles.css](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-brook-0sr30?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Sure, I'll update the example, check it out. The only change I made is that I gave the button a unique ID called `playBtn` and the image a unique ID called `cover` and when the click event happens we just remove the both cover and playBtn.

Answer (score 0):

replace `this.remove();` with

```
document.querySelectorAll('.one, .two').forEach((el) => { el.remove(); });
```

or if you prefer

```
clickToPlay.forEach((el) => { el.remove(); });
```